# jQuery : find if a checkbox with another name has the same value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have searched and searched again for a solution but I couldn't find any similar case to mine.

Inside a table, I have a PHP form with checkboxes, generated like this :

```
    while($getalldefenseurs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_check_alldefenseurs)){
        echo '
        <tr class="liste-defenseurs">
            <td>'.$getalldefenseurs['Calciatore'].'&nbsp;('.$getalldefenseurs['Squadra'].')</td>
            <td class="number"><input type="checkbox" class="bouton" value="'.$getalldefenseurs['id'].'" name="titulaire-defenseur"/></td>
            <td class="number"><input type="checkbox" class="bouton"  value="'.$getalldefenseurs['id'].'" name="remplacant-defenseur"/></td>
        </tr>';
    }
```

It gives me something like this :

```
    <tr class="liste-defenseurs">
        <td>LICHTSTEINER&nbsp;(JUVENTUS)</td>
        <td class="number"><input type="checkbox" name="titulaire-defenseur" value="220" id="LICHTSTEINER" class="bouton"></td>
        <td class="number"><input type="checkbox" name="remplacant-defenseur" value="220" class="bouton"></td>
        <td class="number"><input type="checkbox" name="reserviste-defenseur" value="220" class="bouton"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="liste-defenseurs">
        <td>CEPPITELLI&nbsp;(CAGLIARI)</td>
        <td class="number"><input type="checkbox" name="titulaire-defenseur" value="355" id="CEPPITELLI" class="bouton"></td>
        <td class="number"><input type="checkbox" name="remplacant-defenseur" value="355" class="bouton"></td>
        <td class="number"><input type="checkbox" name="reserviste-defenseur" value="355" class="bouton"></td>
    </tr>
```

As you can see, I can't know the value of each checkbox but I know their name.

The thing is I don't want any checkbox having the same value to be checked at the same time.
So in my javascript I tried this code below, but it doesn't always work and I think it is due to the order in which I check the boxes in my table...

```
$("tr.liste-defenseurs td input:checkbox").on('change',function(e) {    
    if($("input[name='remplacant-defenseur']:checked").val() == $("input[name='titulaire-defenseur']:checked").val()) {
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
       alert("You can't check 2 checkboxes on the same line at the same time.");
    }
});
```

Could anyone help me correct my jQuery code for it to work please ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The thing is I don't want any checkbox having the same value to be checked at the same time.

So regardless of the name of the checkbox, if a box is checked, you want to uncheck all others with the same *value*? You can select on `value`:

```
$("tr.liste-defenseurs td input:checkbox").on('change',function(e) {
    $('input[type=checkbox][value="' + this.value + '"]')
        .not(this)
        .prop("checked", false);
});
```

---

Side note: When you use jQuery pseudo-selectors like `input:checkbox`, you force jQuery to handle processing the selector in JavaScript code rather than handing off to the browser's much more efficient own selector processing. Sometimes that's worth it, but I'd use `input[type=checkbox]` rather than `input:checkbox` as the latter really doesn't buy you anything...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick and easy solution, it works like a charm! Your advice helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very used to stackoverflow - however I can not see where name='remplacant-attaquant'] and name='titulaire-attaquant'] are referenced in the out put table.

One alternative you can try is to simply check $(this).val() against an array of checked vars.

```
var selected_groups = $("input[name='names-french']:checked").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
```

This would solve it - but I think it is a naming issue from the outset.

Comment: Yes sorry I have a long code and I copied the wrong line, I meant name='remplacant-defenseur' and name='titulaire-defenseur', I will change that !

Thanks a lot for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr.liste-defenseurs td input:checkbox").on('change',function(e) {    
   if($('input[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]:checked').length > 1){
     alert("You can't check 2 checkboxes on the same line at the same time.");
     $(this).attr('checked',false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var array = [];
    $('table').find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).on('change',function(){         if(jQuery.inArray( $(this).val(), array ) === -1){
            array.push($(this).val());
            $(this).prop("checked",true);
            }else{
                alert("You cant check!!");
                $(this).prop("checked",false);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

This works fine for me!!